# Preventing UAC from suspending my app temporally

Tags: vb.net, security, uac

I am currently building an application that controls mouse and other important windows shortcuts through a modified joystick in order to be used by handicapped. The problem is application is temporally suspended when UAC dialog is shown. Knowing that my program isn't triggering the UAC prompt, it's that anything that triggers it causes his app to halt processing.

i.e. I cannot control mouse cursor through joystick when the computer is in any secure desktop (such as UAC, CTRL + ALT + DEL, etc.)

Is there any way to keep the application running without suspension just like windows accessibility programs such as narrator, on screen keyboard and so on?

I have tried disabling windows secure desktop from regedit but there no much change. I know that I can disable UAC completely but I don't want to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HansPassant My program isn't triggering the UAC prompt, it's that anything that triggers it causes his app to halt processing.

Comment: Your app cannot turn off the UAC prompt for what other processes/apps are doing. There's no way to "suspend UAC" while your app is running. (If there was, it would be a great security hole for malware. "Get the user to run my app as a non-admin, suspend UAC, do whatever bad things I want, unsuspend UAC, and pretend nothing bad happened.")

Comment: @KenWhite But I think there is way to inject my application into the secure desktop.

Comment: As I said, I don't believe there is (because of the security issue). I could be wrong, but I don't think so. :-) Good luck.